# Use a bash file to open a lxterminal and run commands into it automatically

Tags: raspbian, python, script, bash, lxterminal

I have made a python application for raspberry and it needs to run into a terminal. That's totally necessary.

To do that I wrote two bash files, run_.sh and launcher.sh.

run_.sh execute the python application, while launcher.sh invoke a lxterminal and execute run_.sh

When I manually run launcher.sh with the command:

```
sh launcher.sh
```

It works well. The terminal opens, the application runs and everything is ok. But when launcher.sh have to be executed in raspberry's startup, it doesn't work.

I'm using a raspberry pi 3 Raspbian: kernel version 4.14

Method of execute on startup:

```
sudo crontab -e
@reboot sh /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

The startup's method is working. That's no the problem.
The problem is that the commando that open the xlterminal doesn't work on startup. It works, when I excute manually, but not automatically.

This is what is write into my bash files.

launcher.sh:

```
lxterminal --command="/bin/bash -c '/home/pi/run_.sh; /bin/bash'"
```

run_.sh

```
python3 application.py
```

I expect that a xlterminal appears and execute the commands into run_.sh. But It show me this error:

```
(lxterminal:1005): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run something at startup that should open a window, because the X Server is not yet available.

Additionally, cron jobs don't normally have access to the X Server.

However, it is possible to connect to the X Server if you prepare the correct environment.

Normally, what you need are the `DISPLAY`, `XAUTHORITY` and `XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME` variables. To verify that, run

```
env -i \
    DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=$XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME \
    /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh
```

The line breaks are for better readability. The command `env -i` will run the command that follows with a clear environment, just with the values explicitly set on the command line.

If that works, you need to find out the correct values for those variables for your `crontab`, and add a sufficient delay for the X Server to start:

```
@reboot sleep 30; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=... XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=... /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh
```

As you probably don't use `/home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh` for something else, you can also add the commands to that file instead of the crontab line. This assumes you made the script executable.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Ralf.

Your test commando works well, but I'm not sure what is XAUTHORITY and XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME. Please, can you explain me? How can I find out these values?

I tried with:

reboot sleep 120; DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=$XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME /home/pi/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1


But it doesn't work. It show me the same error:

(lxterminal:1005): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You can't use `XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY` in the crontab, because that assumes that `XAUTHORITY` is already set, which is true in the shell, but not in the crontab. Use `echo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=$XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME` in the shell to show the current values.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your commands in `~/.bashrc` and they'll be executed when you open a terminal.

Comment: Thanks for answer, ben.
Yes that's an option, but I wan to automatically open a xlterminal and excute commands into it automatically.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: This is very bad advice. .bashrc is for configuring the shell and should not be used to run programs

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the init level may not be set high enough yet for an X session.  You might add a sleep 120 to the cron and possibly a nohup:

```sh
@reboot sleep 120;nohup /bin/sh /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

*(edit: I also fully qualified the `/bin/sh` but I doubt that's the issue)*

Comment: Hi,Steve.
Thanks for your support.
I thought tha same, but that's not the solution.
It still doesn't work.